# Obtener registros cuyo mes coincida con el aplicado en la fecha sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Estoy creando un consulta para obtener todos los registros en los cuales el mes coincida con la fecha que obtengo, para esto he intentado lo siguiente:

```
declare @printDate DATE = CONVERT(date, getdate())
--print @printDate Conocer el valor en la variable
select * from tercero
where MONTH(convert(DATE, fecha_nacimiento, 103)) = @printDate
```

pero me tilda el siguiente error

> Mens. 206, Nivel 16, Estado 2, Línea 3
>   Conflicto de tipos de operandos: date es incompatible con int

Que puede ser?, Cabe indicar que mi campo `fecha_nacimiento` es de tipo `DATETIME`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay varios aspectos que mejorar en tu consulta. Primero que todo, el error se debe a que la función `MONTH` entrega como resultado un número entero entre 1 y 12 (uno para cada mes del año), y tu parámetro es de tipo de `date`.

Ahora, voy a asumir que la columna `fecha_nacimiento` no es ni `datetime` ni `date`, sino un string (ya que entonces no sería necesario hacer `CONVERT(date,fecha_nacimiento,103)`. Esto hace que sea difícil aplicar el filtro que quieres sin utilizar alguna función de conversión sobre tu columna, te recomiendo por temas de performance y buenas prácticas usar siempre el tipo de dato que corresponda en cada columna (para fecha de nacimiento, sería date).

En este caso, lo más simple (si bien no lo que te entregará mejor performance) es usar:

```
WHERE MONTH(CONVERT(date,fecha_nacimiento,103)) = MONTH(@printDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que como quieres comparar es el mes con utilizas las funcion MOTH te devuelve un entero y como `@printDate` lo que te trae es una fecha te lanza el error,

solucion debes convertir `@printDate` en int y listo, tu codigo deberia quedar asi,

```
declare @printDate INT = MONTH(CONVERT(date, getdate()))
--print @printDate Conocer el valor en la variable

SELECT @printDate
select * from tercero
where MONTH(convert(DATE, fecha_nacimiento, 103)) = @printDate
```

espero que te funcione.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero en la ultima linea debes compararla frente a fecha_nacimiento no contra getdate()